# How do I set collection view's cell size via the auto layout

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, ios-autolayout

Hi I'm trying to resize the cell via the `auto layout`.

I want display the cell by the 3 by 3.

First Cell's margin left=0

Last Cell's margin right=0

And all of the cell's space has 1pt. Like an `instagram`.

[image]

[image]

Should I set to Cell's Size? I want set constraint via the Autolayout.

I also trying to set cell's size using the code.

Here is my code:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSizeMake(123, 123);
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 1;
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 1;
}
```

But..I think it is not exactly calculate the cell's size.

How do I set cell's size depending on the screen's size?

I have to set space the 1pt between cell's.

Is there anyway to set only using the storyboard?

If not, How do I set by the code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I don't believe you can set the size by only using the Storyboard because you can't set constraints to recurring items like collection view cells that are created on the fly at runtime.

You can easily compute the size from the information you are given. In `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)` you can access the bounds of the `collectionView` to compute the desired size of your cell:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    // Compute the dimension of a cell for an NxN layout with space S between
    // cells.  Take the collection view's width, subtract (N-1)*S points for
    // the spaces between the cells, and then divide by N to find the final
    // dimension for the cell's width and height.

    let cellsAcross: CGFloat = 3
    let spaceBetweenCells: CGFloat = 1
    let dim = (collectionView.bounds.width - (cellsAcross - 1) * spaceBetweenCells) / cellsAcross
    return CGSize(width: dim, height: dim)
}
```

Make sure your class adopts the protocol `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`.

This then works for iPhones and iPads of all sizes.

Comment: Don't collection view cells support automatic sizing now?

Comment: I don't know @ThuggishNuggets.  You'd have to somehow provide the same kind of information that I'm handling here such as number of cells across and desired spacing between the cells.  If you know of another or better way to do it, please add an answer.

Comment: Thanks you so much~!

Comment: Thanks you so much~! I've test your code on iPhone6. It really helpful! :) I have a one more question. It seems all of the cell's width is 124. And It has a gap 1pt. First Cell and Second Cell is looks great but Second and Last Cell's gap is small. I think it is happened because of the float values like an 124.3333.

Comment: I would just make the gap a little larger to make the difference less noticeable.

Comment: @vacawama I understand thanks for the helping me. I'm really appreciate for you :)

Comment: Worked       `return CGSize(width: ((collectionView.frame.size.width/2)-2) , height: (collectionView.frame.size.width/2)-2)` in my case

Comment: And don't forget to set Estimate Size to None on Size Inspector if you are using this method. Unless it won't work..

Comment: Please do I need to implement something before I can access `sizeForItemAt` ? Because I cant find it

Comment: @DanielKabuAsare, make sure your class adopts `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`.

Answer (score 16):

Great answer by vacawama but I had 2 issues. I wanted the spacing that I defined in storyboard to automatically be used.

[image]

And secondly, I could not get this function to invoke and no one mentioned how? In order to invoke the collectionView's sizeForItemAt you need to extend **UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout** instead of extending UICollectionViewDelegate. I hope this saves someone else some time.

```
extension MyViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let cellsAcross: CGFloat = 3
        var widthRemainingForCellContent = collectionView.bounds.width
        if let flowLayout = collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            let borderSize: CGFloat = flowLayout.sectionInset.left + flowLayout.sectionInset.right
            widthRemainingForCellContent -= borderSize + ((cellsAcross - 1) * flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing)
        }
        let cellWidth = widthRemainingForCellContent / cellsAcross
        return CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: cellWidth)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7):

I set it up using CollectionView's delegate methods. This will give you a 2xN setup but you can easily make it a 3xN instead.  Here's a screenshot and you can refer to my project on GitHub...

https://github.com/WadeSellers/GoInstaPro

[image: CollectionView flow layout screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3 version code** based on vacawama answer:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let cellsAcross: CGFloat = 3
        let spaceBetweenCells: CGFloat = 1
        let dim = (collectionView.bounds.width - (cellsAcross - 1) * spaceBetweenCells) / cellsAcross

        return CGSize(width: dim, height: dim)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution but It only works on iPhone6.

I will trying to update for iphone5/6plus

Special thanks to @vacawama!

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        
        
        // Compute the dimension of a cell for an NxN layout with space S between
        // cells.  Take the collection view's width, subtract (N-1)*S points for
        // the spaces between the cells, and then divide by N to find the final
        // dimension for the cell's width and height.
        
        let cellsAcross: CGFloat = 3
        let spaceBetweenCells: CGFloat = 1
        let dim = (collectionView.bounds.width - (cellsAcross - 1) * spaceBetweenCells) / cellsAcross
                print(indexPath.row)
        
        var width = dim
        
        //last cell's width
        if(  (indexPath.row + 1) % 3 == 0){
            width = 124
            
        }else {
            width = 124.5
        }
        print(width)
        return CGSize(width: width , height: dim)
        
    }
    
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 1;
    }
    
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 1;
    }
```