# How to set spacing between collectionview cells in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, layout, uicollectionview

currently i am using swift 3 and storyboard, googled everything and looked over all stackoverflow similar questions, got nothing so far.

On my example Porject,

my Collection view looks like this
[Simulator Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4quoX.png)

which is not what i want, i want a grid layout with no spacing at all, i edited the storyboard values ddin't got anything there,  so for that  i used this code

```
  let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 5, bottom: 0, right: 5)
layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width / 2, height: width / 2)
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
collectionView!.collectionViewLayout = layout
```

didn't work either :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38028456/1630618

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
'if let layout = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout{
            let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
            layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 5, bottom: 0, right: 5)
            layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width / 2, height: width / 2)
            layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
            layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        }'
```